# Initializing C array in C++ class

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a C++ class that contains a private C array as follows,

```
class DataObject {
    private:
        double* data_array_;
};
```

Due to restrictions from other parts in the program that are not shown, I can't use a `std::vector<double>`, can't use the `DataObject` constructor to initialize the array (initializer list?), and would prefer not to allocate the array on the heap. As such, I have to initialize the array in an `init()` function, which takes in the number of array elements as its argument. So far I've tried the following, but unfortunately they don't seem to work:

Attempt 1:

```
void DataObject::init(unsigned int num_elements) {
    data_array_[num_elements];
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
void DataObject::init(unsigned int num_elements) {
    data_array_ = double[num_elements];
}
```

Thus, I was wondering if there's another way to initialize a stack allocated private C array given the above restrictions.

Comment: This is pure C++ question. There are no stack-allocated variable length arrays in C++. What you want cannot be done, period.

Comment: Given that the member is a pointer, and you don’t know the number of elements at compile time, you have no choice but to allocate the array dynamically at runtime. But why can’t you use the constructor for that? At least use the constructor to initialize the pointer to null, in case the destructor is called to free the array before `init()` is called. And don’t forget to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage the array correctly.

Comment: Why can't you use a `vector<double>`? It should be pretty easy to plug-in whereever a `double*` is needed (just use `data_array_.data()` in those places). Why don't you want to use the heap?

Comment: you could use `alloca` if you are into S/M but it is generally not recommended since it can cause lots of issues and UB. I think you need to bite the bullet and use the heap for this kind of requirement, if you still need a pointer and not a template then at least use a smart pointer for it. std::unique_ptr<double[]>. At this point you have not really explained why you cannot use a std::vector though so it is hard to help.

Comment: The above-mentioned limitations of not being able to use a `std::vector<double>` and not being able to use a constructor are due to limitations when performing GPU parallelization with OpenACC directives. Since it seems like the only way to go is to use heap allocation, I'll head down that route, but just wanted to know if a stack allocated approach was possible.

Comment: How will the OpenACC directives even know that you're using a `vector<double>` if you do  `double* foo = data_array_.data();` and use `foo` within those directives? Which OpenACC directive are you planning to use that won't be able to handle `vector<double>` as-is?  "_With OpenACC, programmer keeps the existing code intact and delivers faster performance when an accelerator is available in the system._" seems to indicate that you should be able to use the proper container.

Comment: _"Due to restrictions from other parts in the program that are not shown, I can't use a std::vector<double>"_... often it is possible, if you interface it properly. But this sounds like an XY-problem to me. What are you trying to solve and why is it a problem? We need *way* more details.

Comment: _" due to limitations when performing GPU parallelization"_ wait what? You do know that accessing main memory from GPU is very slow? So you should copy the data to the GPU memory anyhow. and that's a dynamic allocation.

Comment: @AndersK `alloca()` won’t work in this case. It allocates stack space in the current stack frame only. When `init()` exits, that stack space will be freed, leaving `data_array_` dangling.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes you are of course right, he would instead need to have some global data area which he maintains by himself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a C++ class that contains a private C array as follows,
>
> ```
>    double* data_array_;
> ```

That is not an array. That is a pointer. As such, your class doesn't and cannot "contain" an array at all. It can only point to (element of) an array that is contained somewhere else.

If you want to point to an automatic array, the only way to do that is to pass (pointer, reference or span to the) array as an argument. Example:

```
void DataObject::init(double* data_array_, std::size_t num_elements) {
    this->data_array_ = data_array_; this is becom
    this->num_elements = num_elements;
}

void foo() {
    constexpr std::size_t num_elements = 42;
    double data_array_[num_elements];

    DataObject example{};
    example.init(data_array_, num_elements);
}
```

Note that as a referential type, you must be very careful to keep the pointed array alive at least as long as the `DataObject` which points to it is alive. Otherwise the pointer will be left dangling. Also note that the class is becoming to look like a limited re-implementation of `std::span` with dynamic extent. It might be better to just use that instead.

If you need `DataObject` to control the lifetime of the array (which will be safer since you can avoid dangling), and the size of the array is determined at runtime, then dynamic allocation is your only option (C++ doesn't have flexible array members that C does). If you cannot use `std::vector`, then I recommend using another implementation of the same datastructure. That said, I suspect that it may be possible that you're mistaken in your assumption that you cannot use `std::vector`.